# how to catch in jquery the event: user liked & shared current page of website

Tags: jquery, facebook, events, share, facebook-like

I have an online store. We want to give discount if the user gave facebook like and share on the product page. how can I detect this event?

I tried to catch the click event's facebook buttons but it is not a good solution because the user can click again and longer to give unlike.

There may be some facebook api possible to show whether this URL received from this user a like and a share. I searched but did not find anything about it :(

P.s. sorry for my bad english. I translated on google translate

Comment: It's definite on facebook that you need to rely on. Websites like http://addmefast.com depend on stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You can´t.

...at least not anymore. Like Gating or rewarding the user for liking or sharing something is not allowed anymore:

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

- https://developers.facebook.com/policy/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

The only way to implement this would be to authorize a user with the `user_likes` permissions, but you will not get it approved for that. But again: It´s not allowed. Users need to like/share something because they really want to, not because they get something for it.